# is it ok to update a record based on a field even if the said field is not updated with new value?

Tags: dml, bestpractice

I have a class that computes tax code for a given account and updates the tax code field with the new calculated value. Now irrespective of whether the tax code generated is different from the existing tax code value I am doing an update. Is it bad to not put a check to see if the new value is different from the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not checking beforehand is a performance drain, and will count against your governor limits for the transaction. You should consider making updates only when necessary. There is a point where the answer is "it doesn't matter" (some really light-weight objects won't really feel a difference), but the "heavier" the objects that are involved (more code, more automation), the worse the effect will be.

So, to be clear, the answer is somewhere between "it's not *good*" (but not necessarily "*bad*") to "it's a *really* terrible idea," depending on the context of the objects involved.